# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}(\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}dt)/x^2$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

I am in difficulty when solving limits of two integral functions. I am probably missing practice and the technique that I use may not be optimal. I have

$$\large\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}dt}{x^2}= 1\tag 1 $$
Using L'Hôpital's theorem (deriving gives me the integral function calculated in the extremes) I get $0$ and not $1$ why?
I will have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}dt}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-x^4}-1}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x^3}2\cdot \frac{e^{-x^4}-1}{-x^4}=0$$ with $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{y}-1}{y}=1$$

After I have not understood the solution $-1/10$ of

$$\large\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^{x^2}(\cos t^2 -1)dt}{x^{15}}\tag 2 $$

using always L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Replace $x^2$ with $t$ so that $t\to 0^+$. Then by fundamental theorem of calculus your limit is the value of integrand at $0$ ie $e^{-0^2}=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrongly differentiated the definite integral.

The derivative of definite integral is given by,
$$\boxed{\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\ dt = f(b(x))\cdot b'(x) - f(a(x))\cdot a'(x) }$$

So the derivative of numerator in given limit is,
$$\begin{aligned} \dfrac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}dt& = e^{-x^4} \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2) - e^{0^2}\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}(0) \\ & = e^{-x^4}\cdot 2x - (1)(0) \\&=e^{-x^4}\cdot 2x\end{aligned} $$

And hence the limit (after applying L'Hospital's rule) changes to,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x^4} \cdot 2x}{2x} = \lim_{x\to 0}e^{-x^4} = e^0 = 1 $$

---

***Derivative of definite integral:***

Let's assume that we need to differentiate the following function w.r.t. $x$,$$\displaystyle I(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t) \ dt$$

Suppose the anti-derivative of the function $f(t)$ is $F(t)$, therefore, the function changes to,
$$I(x) = F(t)\bigg|^{b(x)}_{a(x)} = F(b(x)) - F(a(x))$$

According to the fundamental theorem of calculus, differentiation and integration are inverse processes. *If the anti-derivative (integration) of $f(x)$ is $F(x)$, then the derivative of $F(x)$ will be $f(x)$.*

So, the derivative of $I(x)$ is given by,
$$\begin{aligned}I'(x) &= F'(b(x))\cdot b'(x) - F'(a(x))\cdot a'(x)\qquad\rm{\bigg\{Using\ chain\ rule}\bigg\}\\&= f(b(x))\cdot b'(x) - f(a(x))\cdot a'(x)\qquad\rm{\bigg\{Using\ fundamental\ theorem\bigg\}} \end{aligned}$$

Therefore, we have:
$$\boxed{\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\ dt = f(b(x))\cdot b'(x) - f(a(x))\cdot a'(x)}$$

Comment: I not can use the partial derivates with the students of an high school. However thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano You can deduce the formula in that case. $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt = f(b(x))\cdot b'(x) - f(a(x)) \cdot a'(x)$$ Since $a'(x)$ is $0$, the second term will be vanished and you need to deal only with the first expression i.e. $f(b(x)) \cdot b'(x) = e^{-x^4}\cdot 2x$

Comment: In my textbook the last formula not exist. :-(

Comment: There is no formula in the high school book.

Comment: @Sebastiano I've added more details. Hope it helps! Still, if you feel any problems, do let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, by the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of Calculus you have$$\left(\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right)'=2xe^{-x^4}.$$In fact, if $f(x)=\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt$ and $g(x)=x^2$, you have $(f\circ g)(x)=\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt$ and so$$(f\circ g)'(x)=f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)g'(x)=2xe^{-x^4}.$$Therefore\begin{align}\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt}{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cancel{2x}e^{-x^4}}{\cancel{2x}}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}e^{-x^4}\\&=1.\end{align}

Comment: Prof. I didn't understand it. But do I need to derive the integration extremes as the same? Can you explain me the technique, please? Integration extremes what happens to them?

Comment: Let $f(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt$ and let $g(x)=x^2$. Then $f'(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $g'(x)=2x$. Therefore$$(f\circ g)(x)=\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt,$$and\begin{align}(f\circ g)'(x)&=f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)g'(x)\\&=e^{-(x^2)^2}2x\\&=2xe^{-x^4}.\end{align}I don't know what is it that you mean when you write about “to derive the integration extremes”.

Comment: I don't understand the technique. I'm sorry but I welcomed your response. Why $\left(\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right)'=2xe^{-x^4}$?

Comment: Did I not answer that question in my previous comment?

Comment: What needs to be done? For me it is necessary for my students and I can't get it right.

Comment: Yes, prof. I am very confusing.

Comment: Please tell me what is it that you do not understand in my proof that$$\left(\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right)'=2xe^{-x^4}.$$

Comment: @Sebastiano See my answer for that step. I've added more detail.

Comment: How you need to derive when there are integral functions.

Comment: I need to differentiate since otherwise I would not be able to apply L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @Yooo And you have used the Leibniz rule, which is not needed *at all* here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Please can you explain me step by step the general rule to obtain $\left(\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right)'=2xe^{-x^4}$? What are the steps? Can you, please, edit your answer?

Comment: I have already done that.

Comment: Without using function composition is there another possibility? Can you add explain the second limit thus I see the solution step by step?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135959/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-sebastiano).

Answer (score 2):

Option:

Set $y:=x^2$ and consider
$y \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

We get

$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+} \dfrac{\int_{0}^{y}e^{-t^2}dt}{y}.$

Hospital:

$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{e^{-y^2}}{1}=1.$

Or,
using min and max of the strictly decreasing integrand $(y>0):$

$\dfrac{e^{-y^2}\int_{0}^{y}dt}{y} 
\lt \dfrac{\int_{0}^{y}e^{-t^2}dt}{y} \lt \dfrac{e^{0}\int_{0}^{y}dt}{y}.$

Sandwich theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Sebastiano. There is more:))

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution**:

Put $y=x^2.$ Using limit of composite functions, we have
$$L:=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^2} e^{-t^{2}} \mathrm{d} t}{x^{2}} =\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{y} e^{-t^{2}} \mathrm{d} t}{y}.$$

Using L'Hôpital's rule, we obtain
$$L=\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} e^{-y^{2}}=1. $$